# How to disable all attribute menu items in a ul/li List when one of them is clicked?

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, express

I can click on the Photos1, Photos2, Photos3, and Photos4 menus very quickly, and the "$.get(..." is sent to the server 4 times. I need to disable all these menus after any one is clicked. Environment: NodeJS, Express, Pug, Jquery Thanks, Pat

```
--------------DOM----------------------------------
// file = photos.pug
div#wrapper2
    div#altnav
      ul
        include includes/altnav.pug
        include includes/navjs.pug
---------------------------------------------------
// file = includes/altnav.pug
li: a.navigation(href='#', data-level='/images/cs/Photos1') Photos1
li: a.navigation(href='#', data-level='/images/cs/Photos2') Photos2
li: a.navigation(href='#', data-level='/images/cs/Photos3') Photos3
li: a.navigation(href='#', data-level='/images/cs/Photos4') Photos4
---------------------------------------------------
// file = includes/navjs.pug
script.
    $(function(){ // jQuery DOM ready
        $('.navigation').click(function () {

            $(this).css({   // Disable this menu item
                "pointer-events": "none",
                "cursor": "default"
            });
// ??????? I NEED TO DISABLE ALL Menus in this List ???????
            var level = 'm' + $(this).data('level');        // Append an 'm' so I know this came from navjs.pug
            var url = '/navigation?level=' + escape(level); // Send this to the /router/photos.js
            $.get(url, function (data) { 
                $('body').html(data);           // data = new HTML page to be loaded by browser
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: what do you mean by disable all attribute?

Comment: You can use `removeAttr();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to respond to a click event fired by more than one element, you better use event delegation.
I suggest you give your enclosing ul tag a descriptive class name "navigation-menu" so your selector won't target all the ul tags.

```js
$(function(){ // jQuery DOM ready      
    var navigationMenu = $("ul.navigation-menu");
    navigationMenu.on("click", "a", disableLinks);
    function disableLinks(e) {
       navigationMenu.find('a.navigation').css({
        "pointer-events": "none",
        "cursor": "default",
        "color": "#aaa"
      });
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="navigation-menu">
   <li><a class="navigation" href="#link1" >link1</a></li>
   <li><a class="navigation" href="#link2" >link2</a></li>
   <li><a class="navigation" href="#link3" >link3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your code worked perfect. I had problems figuring out the correct jade format for ul. I was using "ul navigation-menu" and it should have been "ul.navigation-menu". All menu items were grayed out and disabled. www.mysite10.com is what I'm working on.

Comment: Jade has a clean syntax but since the structure is entirely determined by the indentation (which is errors prone), sometimes such kind of errors can ruin the end result and there is no easy way to find the error. Anyway, it's a matter of taste after all (if performance isn't a consideration). good luck building and maintaining your website

Answer (score 0):

I would apply an id attribute to all of the elements with `.navigation` and then write a function, passing the id of $(this) to the function and disable all other menu items that don't match that id, like so:

```
function disableAllBut(id) {
    $(.navigation).prop('disable', true);
    $(id).prop('disable', false);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure of the id attribute format. Is it rel='listitem', or alt='listitem', or do I need a "#" sign, or something else.